# Проблема компиляции HelloWorld

Tags: visual-studio, cocos2d

Есть проблема с компиляцией helloWorld в cocos2d(3.16) в Visual Studio 2013.

Я начал искать в git release версию 3.16(потому что я не хочу обновлять VS, так как cocos больше не поддерживает VS2013) Однако, исходя из инструкции, в github для решения проблемы с зависимостями необходимо было выполнить определенные действия.

```
python download-deps.py
git submodule update --init
```

Скаченный же release из github не имеет директории который содержит файлы репозитория и я не могу выполнить последнюю команду для решения проблем с зависимостью и скачивания дополнительных файлов для сборки проекта под vs.

Я клонировал последнюю версию и при помощи команды git checkout перевел проект в состояние релиза 3.16. Затем я выполнив команды, собрал проект и скомпилировал в vs.

Однако при запуске helloWorld у меня вылетает исключение в этом куске кода:

```
    GLViewImpl::GLViewImpl(bool initglfw)
: _captured(false)
, _supportTouch(false)
, _isInRetinaMonitor(false)
, _isRetinaEnabled(false)
, _retinaFactor(1)
, _frameZoomFactor(1.0f)
, _mainWindow(nullptr)
, _monitor(nullptr)
, _mouseX(0.0f)
, _mouseY(0.0f)
{
    _viewName = "cocos2dx";
    g_keyCodeMap.clear();
    for (auto& item : g_keyCodeStructArray)
    {
        g_keyCodeMap[item.glfwKeyCode] = item.keyCode;
    }

    GLFWEventHandler::setGLViewImpl(this);
    if (initglfw)
    {
        glfwSetErrorCallback(GLFWEventHandler::onGLFWError);
        glfwInit();
    }
}
```

В этом моменте:

```
 glfwInit();
```

в файле CCGLViewImpl-desktop.cpp.

логи запуска:

```
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Z:\engine_cocos\cocos\MyFirstProject\MyTraineeProject\proj.win32\Debug.win32\MyTraineeProject.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Z:\engine_cocos\cocos\MyFirstProject\MyTraineeProject\proj.win32\Debug.win32\libcocos2d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Z:\engine_cocos\cocos\MyFirstProject\MyTraineeProject\proj.win32\Debug.win32\sqlite3.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Z:\engine_cocos\cocos\MyFirstProject\MyTraineeProject\proj.win32\Debug.win32\libcurl.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\Wldap32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\normaliz.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Z:\engine_cocos\cocos\MyFirstProject\MyTraineeProject\proj.win32\Debug.win32\libssl-1_1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Z:\engine_cocos\cocos\MyFirstProject\MyTraineeProject\proj.win32\Debug.win32\libcrypto-1_1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Z:\engine_cocos\cocos\MyFirstProject\MyTraineeProject\proj.win32\Debug.win32\websockets.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Z:\engine_cocos\cocos\MyFirstProject\MyTraineeProject\proj.win32\Debug.win32\libmpg123.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Z:\engine_cocos\cocos\MyFirstProject\MyTraineeProject\proj.win32\Debug.win32\libvorbisfile.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Z:\engine_cocos\cocos\MyFirstProject\MyTraineeProject\proj.win32\Debug.win32\libogg.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Z:\engine_cocos\cocos\MyFirstProject\MyTraineeProject\proj.win32\Debug.win32\libvorbis.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Z:\engine_cocos\cocos\MyFirstProject\MyTraineeProject\proj.win32\Debug.win32\OpenAL32.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Z:\engine_cocos\cocos\MyFirstProject\MyTraineeProject\proj.win32\Debug.win32\glew32.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Z:\engine_cocos\cocos\MyFirstProject\MyTraineeProject\proj.win32\Debug.win32\zlib1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\_etoured.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\Nvd3d9wrap.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\nvdxgiwrap.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\dinput8.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\xinput1_3.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Z:\qt\Qt5.11.0\5.11.0\mingw53_32\bin\libEGL.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\MinGw\bin\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'Z:\qt\Qt5.11.0\5.11.0\mingw53_32\bin\libGLESv2.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d8thk.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyTraineeProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\MinGw\bin\libstdc++-6.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in MyTraineeProject.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x754BC9F1 in MyTraineeProject.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

The program '[6252] MyTraineeProject.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Какие у вас мысли насчет этого? Буду рад любому совету.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Все, вопрос закрыт. 
В логах я увидел что некоторые файлы подгружаются из qt и в переменной path я удалил запись вида Qt5.11.0\5.11.0\mingw53_32\bin.